# Accessing values from definstances in CLIPS

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ontology, protege, clips

I am working on a CLIPS program for an assignment that handles electric circuits. I have used Protege to create my ontology and from there I have created the clp file and loaded it into CLIPS. The result is the following:

```
(defclass systemEntity
    (is-a USER)
    (role abstract)
    (single-slot suspect
        (type SYMBOL)
        (allowed-values yes no)
        (default no)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass command
    (is-a systemEntity)
    (role concrete))

(defclass component
    (is-a systemEntity)
    (role abstract))

(defclass sensor
    (is-a component)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot theoretical
        (type INTEGER)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot reading
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 31)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot input
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes internal-component)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass internal-component
    (is-a component)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot short-out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 0)
        (default 0)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (multislot output
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes component)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot msb-out
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 0 15)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot input2
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes systemEntity)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot input1
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes systemEntity)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass adder
    (is-a internal-component)
    (role concrete))

(defclass multiplier
    (is-a internal-component)
    (role concrete))

(defclass circuit
    (is-a systemEntity)
    (role concrete)
    (multislot outputs
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes sensor)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (multislot has-components
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes component)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (multislot inputs
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes command)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass data
    (is-a USER)
    (role abstract)
    (single-slot clock
        (type INTEGER)
        (range 1 ?VARIABLE)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot object
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes systemEntity)
        (create-accessor read-write))
    (single-slot value
        (type INTEGER)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass command_data
    (is-a data)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot object
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes command)
        (create-accessor read-write)))

(defclass reading_data
    (is-a data)
    (role concrete)
    (single-slot object
        (type INSTANCE)
        (allowed-classes sensor)
        (create-accessor read-write)))


(definstances facts
    ([a1] of  adder

    (input1 [input_1])
    (input2 [input_1])
    (output
        [m1]
        [p1])
    (short-out 0)
    (suspect no))

([a2] of  adder

    (input1 [p1])
    (input2 [p2])
    (output [out1])
    (short-out 0)
    (suspect no))

([circuit_1] of  circuit

    (has-components
        [m1]
        [m2]
        [m3]
        [out1]
        [a1]
        [a2]
        [p1]
        [p2])
    (inputs
        [input_1]
        [input_2]
        [input_3]
        [input_4])
    (outputs [out1])
    (suspect no))

([command_1_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 21))

([command_1_inp2] of  command_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [input_2])
    (value 28))

([command_1_inp3] of  command_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [input_3])
    (value 10))

([command_1_inp4] of  command_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [input_4])
    (value 25))

([input_1] of  command

    (suspect no))

([input_2] of  command

    (suspect no))

([input_3] of  command

    (suspect no))

([input_4] of  command

    (suspect no))

([m1] of  sensor

    (input [a1])
    (suspect no))

([m2] of  sensor

    (input [p1])
    (suspect no))

([m3] of  sensor

    (input [p2])
    (suspect no))

([out1] of  sensor

    (input [a2])
    (suspect no))

([p1] of  multiplier

    (input1 [input_2])
    (input2 [a1])
    (output
        [m2]
        [a2])
    (short-out 0)
    (suspect no))

([p2] of  multiplier

    (input1 [input_3])
    (input2 [input_4])
    (output
        [m3]
        [a2])
    (short-out 0)
    (suspect no))

([reading_1_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [m1])
    (value 10))

([reading_1_m2] of  reading_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [m2])
    (value 24))

([reading_1_m3] of  reading_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [m3])
    (value 26))

([reading_1_out] of  reading_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [out1])
    (value 18))
)
```

I am trying to figure out how to make defrules to print out all the inputs and outputs from a specific isntance of a class such as the adder a1. I will show what I mean below, by showing a few definstances:

```
([a1] of  adder

    (input1 [input_1])
    (input2 [input_1])
    (output
        [m1]
        [p1])
    (short-out 0)
    (suspect no))
```

a1 adder takes as input1 and input2 the input_1 instance which is this:

```
([command_1_inp1] of  command_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [input_1])
    (value 21))
```

and outputs to m1 and p1 from which the output can be obtained by the m1 instance which is this:

```
([reading_1_m1] of  reading_data

    (clock 1)
    (object [m1])
    (value 10))
```

However when I try to access the values of an instance (e.g. of the first input) I get an error `No object of existing classes can satisfy is-a restriction in object pattern.`

```
(defrule find-input-1
    (object (is-a command_data)
    (clock ?clock)
    (value ?value))
    =>
    (printout t ?clock " " ?value crlf))
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I access the values that my instances have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use the **object** keyword in your rule, otherwise CLIPS treats internal-component as if it was a deftemplate fact.

```
(defrule print-sensor
    (object (is-a internal-component) (input1 ?input1) (input2 ?input2))
    =>
    (printout t ?input1 " " ?input2 crlf))
```

You also need to declare the internal-component class as reactive to use it in rules.

```
(defclass internal-component
    (is-a component)
    (role concrete)
    (pattern-match reactive)
    .
    .
    .
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer mr Gary. I tried this but I see nothing printed in console. I also realized that maybe I didn't explain very well what I want to accomplish. What I want to do is for example to be able get the values of the input (input_1 and input_1) that is given to the adder (a1) along with the value of the output (that is given to m1 and p1) and then be able to print them. The input value is contained in `([command_1_inp2] of  command_data` and the output value is contained in `([reading_1_m1] of  reading_data`.

Comment: Works fine for me using the code you posted and the change I suggested.